# Custom filter not affecting gtag script position in WordPress footer

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook

I am using a custom filter to place the gtag script in footer if it is applied in functions.php. The filter code is:

```
if (apply_filters('myplugin_ga_script_position', $position = 'footer')) {
    add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'myplugin_add_analytics_code'));
} else {
    add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'myplugin_add_analytics_code'));
}
```

But when I do not use the following filter in functions.php even then the gtag script is in footer:

```
add_filter( 'myplugin_ga_script_position', function( $position ) {
    return 'footer';
});
```

Any fixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the condition to handle the result of the filter call:

```php
if('footer' === apply_filters('myplugin_ga_script_position', 'footer')){
    add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'myplugin_add_analytics_code'));
}else{
    add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'myplugin_add_analytics_code'));
}
```

**EDIT**

After further discussion, depending on how both hooks are implemented a race condition could occur. My updated recommendation is to have two hooks which further register the these hooks.

```php
// This code is the theme's main preference for where the hook
// should be used. We're using the `init` hook which is a
// common hook for this.
add_action(
    'init',
    static function () {
        if ('footer' === apply_filters('myplugin_ga_script_position', 'footer')) {
            add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'myplugin_add_analytics_code'));
        } else {
            add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'myplugin_add_analytics_code'));
        }
    }
);
```

```php
// This is where the theme overrides the previous hook. We're
// using an earlier hook so that it gets registered before the
// other hook gets invoked.
add_action(
    'after_setup_theme',
    static function () {
        add_filter(
            'myplugin_ga_script_position',
            function ($position) {
                return 'header';
            }
        );
    }
);
```

**EDIT 2**

You absolutely can have custom-named hooks. This is one of WordPress's main ways to extend the system, and it is a great way for plugins to offer defaults for users while still giving advanced users the ability to override them.

But it is important to know, understand and document the hooks and the order that they are called in.

I don't know your specific code, but I think I have a pretty good general ideal of what your setup is. Let's take this code and assume it is written in the bootup code for your plugin:

```
if (apply_filters('myplugin_ga_script_position', $position = 'footer')) {
    add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'myplugin_add_analytics_code'));
} else {
    add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'myplugin_add_analytics_code'));
}
```

Actually, I'm going to go one step further and simply it by just doing this:

```
$script_position = apply_filters('myplugin_ga_script_position', $position = 'footer');
```

Imagine that in your `index.php` (or whatever) of your plugin. Plugins load before themes, so `$script_position` is already set by the time your theme loads. The `apply_filters` code *was* called, however because your theme wasn't loaded yet, it didn't have a chance to register a callback to that hook.

This is a chicken and egg problem. A plugin cannot ask for a theme's input on something until the theme has started loaded.

The fix is what's in the first edit. Your plugin says "when the `init` hook runs, ask anyone if they want to change the default". Your theme then needs to register a response to this, and you must register this response *before* `init` is called.

Also, I'm talking the common pattern of plugin doing one thing and a theme doing another. But the same is true for a plugin customizing its own logic. I would recommend, however, that your plugin doesn't use its own hooks except for exception situations. Personally I would write the plugin code as the following, and only themes (or other plugins) would implement your filter. There's generally no reason for your code (in a single plugin or theme) to implement your filters. That's what your code's logic is for in the first place.

```php
add_action(
    'init',
    static function () {

        // Get the value from the database
        $script_position = get_option('script_position', 'footer');

        if ('footer' === apply_filters('myplugin_ga_script_position', $script_position)) {
            add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'myplugin_add_analytics_code'));
        }

        if ('header' === apply_filters('myplugin_ga_script_position', $script_position)) {
            add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'myplugin_add_analytics_code'));
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I have applied this using following in functions.php but not worked:
````
add_filter( 'analytify_ga_script_position', function( $position ) {
    return 'footer';
});
```

Comment: Are you calling `add_filter` in another filter, or is it bare in your functions.php?

Comment: it depends on user preference. By default add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'analytify_add_analytics_code')); is used but if a user wants to place it in footer then he can use the filter in functions.php

Comment: What I'm asking is where `add_filter( 'analytify_ga_script_position', function( $position ) { return 'footer'; })` is placed. If that code is placed in a hook that runs later it might be too late.

Comment: it is placed in functions.php

Comment: Okay, then you probably have a race condition. Is both the `apply_filters` and `add_action` calls in the same theme, or is one in a plugin and one in a theme?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257251/discussion-between-ahmedwp-and-chris-haas).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't chat, my job pulls me away from the computer too much. I would recommend looking into the [hook call](https://rachievee.com/the-wordpress-hooks-firing-sequence/) order in general. If you don't register your hooks in another hook, and instead they are just bare, you will need to come up with your own way of identifying the order that they get called in. If you register your hooks using the core hooks, they will take care of this for you.

Comment: But still one clarity needed cannot I have a custom named action/filter as this is for the customers that use the application